# Retrieve an Objects Parent Container Object in WPF

Tags: wpf, object, parent, observablecollection

I have nested **ObsevableCollections** as seen below. For simplistic reason this is sample code of what I am trying to accomplish.

Sample application the contains a **ObservableCollection** Team

```
    class MyApplication2
    {
        ObservableCollection<Team> _Teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>();
        public MyApplication2()
        {
            _Teams.Add(new Team("Team1"));
            _Teams.Add(new Team("Team2"));
            _Teams.Add(new Team("Team3"));

            foreach (Team t in _Teams)
            {
                t.Territories.Add(new Territory("Territory1"));
                t.Territories.Add(new Territory("Territory2"));
                t.Territories.Add(new Territory("Territory3"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Team object that contains an **ObservableCollection** Territory object

```
    class Team
    {
        private string _TeamName = "";
        private int _TeamProperty1 = 0;
        ObservableCollection<Territory> _Territories = new ObservableCollection<Territory>();

        public Team(string tName)
        {
            this.TeamName = tName;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Territory> Territories
        {
            get { return _Territories; }
            set { _Territories = value; }
        }

        public string TeamName
        {
            get { return _TeamName; }
            set { _TeamName = value; }
        }

        public int TeamProperty1
        {
            get { return _TeamProperty1; }
            set { _TeamProperty1 = value; }
        }

    }
```

Territory object

```
    class Territory
    {
        private string _TerritoryName = "";

        public Territory(string tName)
        {
            this.TerritoryName = tName;
        }

        public string TerritoryName
        {
            get { return _TerritoryName; }
            set { _TerritoryName = value; }
        }

        public void Method1()
        {
            //Do Some Work
        }
    }
```

Just for this example I assigned t a value but in my real code I have the object **t** from some other means. **t** is an object type of territory in an **ObservableCollection** of Territories inside and object of a Team.

```
        public void SomeWork()
        {
            Territory t = _Teams[1].Territories[0];
            SomeMoreWork(t);
        }
```

I am removing a territory from 1 team and adding it to another team. Something like the following. How I get what Team object the territory belongs to?

```
        public void SomeMoreWork(Territory t)
        {
            Team _Team = ( Parent of t? );
            _Team.Territories.Remove(t);
            _Teams[0].Territories.Add(t);
        }
```

Comment: I think the best way would be to add data member inside the Territory class that associates it with the appropriate Team object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the info [Vincent Piel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856501/vincent-piel).

Thank you for the idea [Saad Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756262/saad-imran).

I changed the following and added an AssociatedTeam to my territory object and set it in the consructor. So far it seems to do what Im looking for.

```
    class Territory
    {
        private string _TerritoryName = "";
        Team _AssociatedTeam = null;

        public Territory(string tName, Team team)
        {
            this.TerritoryName = tName;
            this.AssociatedTeam = team;
        }

        public Team AssociatedTeam
        {
            get { return _AssociatedTeam; }
            set { _AssociatedTeam = value; }
        }

        public string TerritoryName
        {
            get { return _TerritoryName; }
            set { _TerritoryName = value; }
        }


        public void Method1()
        {
            //Do Some Work
        }
    }
```

And then change the initiation of territory in the constructor of MyApplication

```
        t.Territories.Add(new Territory("Territory1", t));
        t.Territories.Add(new Territory("Territory2", t));
        t.Territories.Add(new Territory("Territory3", t));
```

Answer (score 2):

In MyApplication2 a linq query like :

```
var TeamsOwnTTerritory = from team in _Teams
                         where team.Territories.Contains(t)
                         select team
```

will bring you the list of team having the t territory.

Rq : So far with your code nothing ensures that several teams do not own the same territory.

Comment: And i will add to my answer : NO object has ANY mean to know to which other object it 'belongs'. To have such awareness (like the garbage collector which knows if anyone uses an object, or the UIElements and their VisualParents, amongst other examples) the object have to do some more efforts. In your example, you could manage a 'Pool' of territories to ensure only one team owns a territory, and have each territory know about its owner.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the info. I think I figured a way to make this work. I will post an aswer in a bit.

Comment: which could mean i 'answered' your question, mate :=)

Comment: =) Answered yes, but I didn't go this route. Helped me figure a direction yes, so up votes for you. I'll have to wait 8hrs before I can post what I did. I'm still a newb here and they wont let me answer my own question yet =(